# Give circle random direction after hitting another circle in p5.js

Tags: javascript, random, p5.js, direction

Im am creating a COVID-19 simulator where every circle in the simulation is a person. When two persons hit each other, i want the direction that they "bounce" off each other to be random. Currently i just mirror the current speed, which means the the persons follow a pre defined path, even when bouncing of each other.

This is my "move" function

```
 move() {
        if (this.willMove) {
            this.xPos += this.xSpeed;
            this.yPos += this.ySpeed;
        }
    }
```

This where i do my collision detection

```
collision(other) {
        let distance = dist(this.xPos, this.yPos, other.xPos, other.yPos);

        if (distance < this.personRadius + other.personRadius) {
            this.changeDirection();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The things handeling the changing of direction:

```
changeDirection() {
        this.mirrorXSpeed();
        this.mirrorYSpeed();
    }

    mirrorXSpeed() {
        this.xSpeed = this.xSpeed * -1;
    }

    mirrorYSpeed() {
        this.ySpeed = this.ySpeed * -1;
    }
```

I have tried multiplying the speed by -0.95, but this just decreases the speed.

The full project can be found here: https://github.com/perkynades/Simulation-of-COVID19/tree/part1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help, it will make all the people bounce in a random direction when called.

You will have to add this.speed to your person constructor, and make sure angle mode is set to radians.

```
changeDirection() {
        //This next line will change the speed by a random amount, 
        //delete it if you don't like it,  
        //or change the range for a different behavior
        this.speed += random(1,3) * random([-1,1])


        let ang = random(PI * 2)
        this.changeXSpeed(ang);
        this.changeYSpeed(ang);
    }

    changeXSpeed(ang) {
        this.xSpeed = this.speed * cos(ang);
    }

    changeYSpeed(ang) {
        this.ySpeed = this.speed * sin(ang);
    }
}
```

If you want a more realistic bounce, I would check out Chris courses video on [Collision detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=789weryntzM) it gives a natural fell to circle on circle collisions, and even though it is not all P5.js, it is was very helpful to me and I hope that it will be for you too.

Comment: Thank you so much, this made my simulation much more realistic. Only thing i changed was "this.speed += ..." to "this.speed =....". Because with the "+" all the people in my simulation sudently got lightning fast

Comment: Yeah, now that I look at it, the += was a mistake on my part, and should definitely not be incremented like that, glad it helped though :)